# asking about Javascript remoting in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, remoting

I am trying to use JavaScript remoting in Salesforce. I have a textbox where I input a city name to find. The first time I clicked the search button I got the right result but when I clicked on it another time I got many duplicated columns. I don't know where I have gone wrong. Please help me. Here is my code:

**Controller Class:**

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {
    public static List<Account> account { get; set; }
    public AccountRemoter() { } 

    @RemoteAction
    global static List<Account> getAccount(String cityName) {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, City__c, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name FROM Account WHERE City__c = :cityName];
        return account;
    }
}
```

**Visual page:**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">

    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.knockout}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.kendo, '/js/jquery.min.js')}"/> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var VM = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.items = ko.observableArray();

                self.columnNames = ko.computed(function () {
                    if (self.items().length === 0)
                        return [];
                    var props = [];
                    var obj = self.items()[0];

                    for (var name in obj)
                        props.push(name);
                    return props;
                });
           };

        function getRemoteAccount() {
            var cityName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}', cityName, function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {


                       var vm = new VM();

                       ko.applyBindings(vm);

                       //vm.items.removeAll();

                       for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                            vm.items.push({                                 
                                'Name': result[i].Name,
                                'City': result[i].City__c
                            });
                       }

                    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                        document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML =  event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
                    }
                }, 
                {escape: true}
            );
        }
    </script>

    <input id="acctSearch" type="text"/>
    <button onclick="getRemoteAccount()">Search</button>
    <div id="responseErrors"></div>


    <div id="dv">
    <table style="float:left;" Id="mytable">
       <thead >
            <tr data-bind="foreach: columnNames" >
                <th> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columnNames">
                <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>  

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score -1):

try `self.items.removeAll();` before `applyBindings()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried but it did not work:
  
  var vm = new VM();

  vm.items.removeAll();

  ko.applyBindings(vm);

Comment: You have to clear VM object everytime you click on the find button.